# Finding the difference $\log (2) - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{100} \frac {1} {2^n \cdot n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, approximation

> > The difference  $$\log (2) - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{100} \frac {1} {2^n \cdot n}\ \ \ \ \ \ \text {is}$$
> >
> > $(1)$ less than $0.$
> >
> > $(2)$ greater than $1.$
> >
> > $(3)$ less than $\frac {1} {2^{100} \cdot 101}.$
> >
> > $(4)$ greater than $\frac {1} {2^{100} \cdot 101}.$

It is clear that $(2)$ is false because  $\log (2) - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{100} \frac {1} {2^n \cdot n} < \log (2) < 1.$ What other options are true?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: Think about what $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n \cdot n}$ converges to. Can you recognize what function the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$ represents?

Comment: I know that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^n} {n!} = e^x.$

Comment: That's a good start, you've seen the Taylor series for $e^x.$ Have you seen the series for $\log(1+x)$ ?

Comment: Yeah sure. It is of the form $$x - \frac {x^2} {2} + \frac {x^3} {3} - \cdots = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac {x^n} {n}.$$

Comment: Alright. Then can you see why $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n n} = \log(1/2)$?

Comment: Oh! I see. It can be obtained by putting $x = -\frac 1 2$ in the Taylor series expansion for $\log (1 + x).$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102189/discussion-between-ragib-zaman-and-math-maniac).

Comment: That clearly means that $\log (2) - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^n \cdot n} > 0.$ So $(1)$ is definitely false. What about $(3)$ and $(4)$ @Ragib Zaman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Ragib Zaman I finally able to do it. Here it is $:$

We first observe that $$\log (2) = - \log \left ( \frac 1 2 \right ) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^n \cdot n}.$$ So $$\log (2) - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{100} \frac {1} {2^n \cdot n} = \sum\limits_{n=101}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^n \cdot n} < \frac {1} {101} \sum\limits_{n=101}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^n} = \frac {1} {2^{100} \cdot 101}.$$